# How to add AjaxControlToolkit to Visual Studio 2013 web-forms template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

It's already to complex and I doubt if I can handle it alone. For now there are a lot of things included to project just from start and I'm not sure for what and what are they are.

I've added AjaxControlToolkit to project and used to setup Script Manager alike:

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods="true"
        EnablePartialRendering="true"
        LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
        AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled">
        <Scripts>

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />


        </Scripts>
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

It looks like something form ajaxToolkit already works but mostly I see errors in Chrome console.

But the first error I see is:

> Uncaught Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts.
>   Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are
>   using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in
>   AjaxControlToolkit.dll. ScriptResource.axd:19

I found a lot of different various scripts in Scripts folder and none provided with AjaxControlToolkit and for now I can't understand how to solve it?

Comment: see if this helps : http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/ajaxcontroltoolkit-version-7-0123-with-net-4-5/ and this http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/05/03/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts/

Comment: @Sam thanks, this http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/ajaxcontroltoolkit-version-7-0123-with-net-4-5/ really helped. May you set it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this links it may help:

[AjaxControlToolkit version 7.0123 with .NET 4.5](http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/ajaxcontroltoolkit-version-7-0123-with-net-4-5/)

[Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts.](http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/05/03/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
Replace `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` to `asp:ScriptManager`

Do this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods="true"
        EnablePartialRendering="true"
        LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
        AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled">
        <Scripts>

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />


        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

I solved similar problem like this.
What it does is the  tag will automatically register latest Asp.net ajax scripts and there won't be any error.

If you're declaring the script manager at the master page, then the child page should have the following:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" />
```